# Query, Find the actor who has participated the most movies as "Principal Actor"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 tables:

1. movies:

| movie_id | movie_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |
| 3 | Name3 |

2. people:

| movie_id | person_name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | producer |
| 2 | name2 | principal actor |
| 3 | name3 | director |

Each movie goes with 1 principal actor but this actor can also go as principal actor to a lot of movies, so, I want to find the person that played the most movies as principal actor, I want an output like this:

| movie_name | person_name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| movie1 | name | principal actor |
| movie2 | name | principal actor |
| movie3 | name | principal actor |

or maybe one like this:

| person_name | count (as principal actor) |
| --- | --- |
| name | 5 |

So far I've tried a subquery but I'm still a beginner and get many errors

Comment: Please, edit your question and add your current code with the description of why it doesn't fit your needs. If it trows some error, then please add an error message in text format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what the expected answer to your question is, your second choice would simply be

```
select person_name, Count(*) as PrincipleActor
from People
where role='principal actor'
group by person_name
order by PrincipleActor desc
```